# C# WebRequest succed with .NET but failed using Mono

Tags: .net, mono

I'm trying to access a Rest API hosted on a web server.
This server has a self signed certificate.
So for dev purpose I overrided the ServicePointManager's ServerCertificateValidationCallback

My program looks like this :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string BASE_URL = "api-endpoint-addr";
        string param = "some-param";

        GetRequest(BASE_URL + param);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /**
     * Accept any certificate (for dev purpose)
     */
    private static bool TrustCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate x509Certificate, X509Chain x509Chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // all Certificates are accepted
        Console.WriteLine("Accepting anyway...");
        return true;
    }

    static void GetRequest(string uri)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = TrustCertificate;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);

    }

    static private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Response CB");
        HttpWebResponse response = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("responseFromServer=" + responseFromServer);
    }

}
```

When it build this code with .NET in VisualStudio all works fine, I can connect to the server and get the JSON but when trying to build it with Mono the TrustCertificate callback is never called (I don't the "Acceptiong anyway..." in the console) and the program stop with the following error :

```
Unhandled Exception : System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: unable to read data from the transport connection : an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

What's the problem here ? I don't really understand why it failed with Mono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

At the beginning of GetRequest(uri) solved the problem.